# Codename One - fixed footer in a scrollable layout

Tags: ios, codenameone, scrollable

I want to realize a form with an image footer, placed on bottom of the view, and a scrollable container, along Y coordinate.

I tried using a BorderLayout: in SOUTH position I put the image footer; in NORTH position I put a scrollable BoxLayout.

The result is I can scroll children elements of BoxLayout, but the footer disappears, if I add too many elements in BoxLayout.

How can I fix that?

---

**EDIT**

I changed my parent layout, from BorderLayout to 2x1 TableLayout (I made it not scrollable): in first row I put the scrollable BoxLayout and in last row I put the image footer. Then I used table contraints in order to increase the heigth of first row and consequently pushing the footer on bottom.

I used the following constraint, when adding the BoxLayout:
`form.add(this.tableLayout.createConstraint(0,0).heightPercentage(90), boxLayout);`

Doing this, I correctly scroll the BoxLayout and the image footer is in a fixed position, near the bottom of the view.

But how can I precisely place to footer on bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved using a BorderLayout as parent layout, placing in CENTER position the scrollable BoxLayout and in SOUTH position the image footer.

Comment: I set as true the scrollableY property of the BoxLayout. Did you mean that?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant